# How to refactor nested subscription in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have an `angular13` app with `rxjs7.5.0`

I need to get list of students based on class code. Here is how I addressed this requirement.

```
export class StudentsComponent implements OnInit {
students: Student[] = [];
private appNum: string;
private sectionCode: string;

constructor(
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private studentSvc: StudentService
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
 this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe((params) => {
  let classCode = params.get('cc') ?? '';

  classCode = decodeURIComponent(classCode);
  if (classCode.match(ALPHABETS_REGEX)) {
    this.studentSvc
      .fetchStudents({
        sec: sectionCode,
      })
      .subscribe((response) => {
        if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.Ok) {
          this.students = response.data(obj);
        }
      });
  }
```

This is functioning as per app requirements. However, I see this would end up in callback & hell chain & is an anti-pattern

Based on the links

- https://angular-checklist.io/default/checklist/rxjs/Z1eFwa9
- https://www.thinktecture.com/en/angular/rxjs-antipattern-1-nested-subs/

> Which operator & how can I get rid of this anti-pattern ?

Thanks!

Comment: This is what operators like switchMap are for.

Comment: @MikeOne, can you please post as answer how can I address it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is something along these lines (see inline comments for explanation)

```
// you start from the this.route.queryParamMap and you transform it
// using a chain of pipeable operators
this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
  // in this case you need only one pipeable operator, switchMap.
  // switchMap is a 'higher order' operator, i.e. an operator which returns
  // another Observable (as part of the transformation performed within
  // the pipe) - other higher order operators are concatMap, mergeMap (akak flatMap, exaustMap)
  switchMap((params) => {
     let classCode = params.get('cc') ?? '';
     classCode = decodeURIComponent(classCode);
     if (classCode.match(ALPHABETS_REGEX)) {
        // in this case you return the Observable returned by fetchStudents
        return this.studentSvc
          .fetchStudents({
            sec: sectionCode,
          })
     }
     // in the case the code does not match ALPHABETS_REGEX you have to return
     // another Observable to respect the signature of switchMap.
     // This Observable could be, for instance, an Observable that returns
     // an empty array (or anything else, depending on your requirement)
     return of([])
  })
).subscribe(
// do what you need to do
)
```

You may find [this article interesting](https://betterprogramming.pub/rxjs-patterns-emerging-from-stackoverflow-asynchronous-api-calls-as-streams-in-the-real-world-ef636c9af19a).

Comment: Thanks! I tried as per your suggestion but this is not triggering the studentSvc.fetchStudents http call

Comment: Is `queryParamMap` notifying anything? You can check this by simply adding a log as first line in the function passed to `switchMap`

Comment: yes It is notifying with the expected values

Comment: Meanwhile I added subscription to the `fetchStudents` using `.subscribe` & I see the expected output. Is it correct?

Comment: No, you should not have nested subscriptions. You should subscribe only once at the end of the `pipe`. I have updated my answer to make this point clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `switchMap` ([Read here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap)) since you have one inner Observable. If you have more than one then you can use `mergeMap` ([Read here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap)).

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

ngOnInit() {
  this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(switchMap((params)=>{
    let classCode = params.get('cc') ?? '';
    if (classCode.match(ALPHABETS_REGEX)) {
      return this.studentSvc.fetchStudents({sec: sectionCode}).pipe((tap((response)=>{
               if (response.status == HttpStatusCode.Ok) {
               this.students = response.data(obj);
            }
         }
         
     )))
    }
  })).subscribe()
}
```

You need also to:

- account for error handling and
- unsubscribe() to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Thanks! I tried as per your suggestion but this is not triggering the `studentSvc.fetchStudents` http call

Comment: you can make the assingment of  this.students = response.data(obj); in  the subscription and remove the pipe from the inner observable. Since the inner observable is wrapped in a condition also be sure that the condition is met.